# Does Visual Studio 2015 have an option for math library consistency

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, floating-point

According to [this documentation](https://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/tc4600/intel/2015.1.133/compiler_f/GUID-D5921FE2-3942-4CD8-B183-85F003AFE9AE.htm), the Intel Fortran Compiler 15.0 has an option `/Qimf-arch-consistency` that “ensures that the math library functions produce consistent results across different microarchitectural implementations of the same architecture…”

Does Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 have a similar option for C++?

Comment: FYI, the [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/629153) in your initial draft is telling somebody that the switch for the **Intel** compiler on Windows is `/Qimf-arch-consistency:true`, not that that switch is for any Microsoft compiler.

Comment: The closest you will get is ``/fp:precise``.